# Updating DateDim table by Table-valued Function Operand type clash

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm creating a `Date` table that also must contain the holidays of Easter (including Good Friday).
Based on code from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), I have now the following Function code:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEasterHolidays](@Year INT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN 
(
  WITH x AS 
  (
    SELECT 
        Date = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, Month, Day)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Month, 
            Day = DaysToSunday + 28 - (31 * (Month / 4))
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                Month = 3 + (DaysToSunday + 40) / 44, DaysToSunday
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    DaysToSunday = paschal - ((@Year + (@Year / 4) + paschal - 13) % 7)
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        paschal = epact - (epact / 28)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            epact = (24 + 19 * (@Year % 19)) % 30
                          ) AS epact
                      ) AS paschal
                  ) AS dts
              ) AS m
          ) AS d
  )
  SELECT 
    Date, 
    HolidayName = 'Easter Sunday' 
  FROM x

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, -2, Date),
    'Good Friday'   
  FROM x

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY,  1, Date), 
    'Easter Monday' 
  FROM x
)
GO
```

I have created my `Date` table as followed:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Date
(
    DateId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Date DATE,
    FullDate CHAR(10), -- Date in MM-dd-yyyy format
    DayOfMonth VARCHAR(2), -- Field will hold day number of Month
    DaySuffix VARCHAR(4), -- Apply suffix as 1st, 2nd ,3rd etc
    DayName VARCHAR(9), -- Contains name of the day, Sunday, Monday
    DayOfWeek CHAR(1),-- First Day Sunday=1 and Saturday=7
    DayOfWeekInMonth VARCHAR(2), --1st Monday or 2nd Monday in Month
    DayOfWeekInYear VARCHAR(2),
    DayOfQuarter VARCHAR(3),
    DayOfYear VARCHAR(3),
    IsWeekday BIT,-- 0=Week End ,1=Week 
    DayWeekOfMonth VARCHAR(1),-- Week Number of Month
    WeekOfQuarter VARCHAR(2), --Week Number of the Quarter
    WeekOfYear VARCHAR(2),--Week Number of the Year
    Month VARCHAR(2), --Number of the Month 1 to 12
    MonthName VARCHAR(9),--January, February etc
    MonthOfQuarter VARCHAR(2),-- Month Number belongs to Quarter
    Quarter CHAR(1),
    QuarterName VARCHAR(9),--First,Second..
    Year CHAR(4),-- Year value of Date stored in Row
    YearName CHAR(7), --CY 2012,CY 2013
    MonthYear CHAR(10), --Jan-2013,Feb-2013
    MMYYYY CHAR(6),
    FirstDayOfMonth DATE,
    LastDayOfMonth DATE,
    FirstDayOfQuarter DATE,
    LastDayOfQuarter DATE,
    FirstDayOfYear DATE,
    LastDayOfYear DATE,
    HolidayName VARCHAR(50),--
    Name of Holiday
)
GO
```

Added information:

I wasn't sure if the following could would help for solving the issue but there are of course also variables. I have placed them under here:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(YEAR, - 10, GETDATE()) --Starting value of Date Range
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 30, @StartDate)) --End Value of Date Range

--Temporary Variables To Hold the Values During Processing of Each Date of Year
DECLARE
    @DayOfWeekInMonth INT,
    @DayOfWeekInYear INT,
    @DayOfQuarter INT,
    @WeekOfMonth INT,
    @CurrentYear INT,
    @CurrentMonth INT,
    @CurrentQuarter INT

/*Table Data type to store the day of week count for the month and year*/
DECLARE @DayOfWeek TABLE
(
    DOW INT,
    MonthCount INT,
    QuarterCount INT,
    YearCount INT
)

INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (2, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (3, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (4, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (5, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (6, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (7, 0, 0, 0)

--Extract and assign various parts of Values from Current Date to Variable

DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATE = @StartDate
SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
```

```sql
WHILE @CurrentDate < @EndDate
/*Begin day of week logic*/
BEGIN
    /*Check for Change in Month of the Current date if Month changed then 
    Change variable value*/
    IF @CurrentMonth != DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET MonthCount = 0
        SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
    END

    /* Check for Change in Quarter of the Current date if Quarter changed then change 
        Variable value*/
    IF @CurrentQuarter != DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET QuarterCount = 0
        SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
    END

    /* Check for Change in Year of the Current date if Year changed then change 
        Variable value*/
    IF @CurrentYear != DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET YearCount = 0
        SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
    END

    -- Set values in table data type created above from variables
    UPDATE @DayOfWeek
    SET 
        MonthCount = MonthCount + 1,
        QuarterCount = QuarterCount + 1,
        YearCount = YearCount + 1
    WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)

    SELECT
        @DayOfWeekInMonth = MonthCount,
        @DayOfQuarter = QuarterCount,
        @DayOfWeekInYear = YearCount
    FROM @DayOfWeek
    WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
```

End of added new information

From there I'm inserting data with the following code:

```sql
INSERT INTO Date
SELECT
    CONVERT (char(8),@CurrentDate,112) as 'DateId',
    @CurrentDate AS 'Date',
    -- CONVERT (char(10),@CurrentDate,105) as 'Date',
    CONVERT (char(10),@CurrentDate,101) as 'FullDate',
    DATEPART(DD, @CurrentDate) AS 'DayOfMonth',

    --Apply Suffix values like 1st, 2nd 3rd etc..
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) IN (11,12,13) THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'th'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 1 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'st'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 2 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'nd'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 3 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'rd'
        ELSE CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'th' 
    END AS 'DaySuffix',
    
    DATENAME(DW, @CurrentDate) AS 'DayName',
    DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate) AS 'DayOfWeek',
    @DayOfWeekInMonth AS 'DayOfWeekInMonth',
    @DayOfWeekInYear AS 'DayOfWeekInYear',
    @DayOfQuarter AS 'DayOfQuarter',
    DATEPART(DY, @CurrentDate) AS 'DayOfYear',
    CASE DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 1
        WHEN 4 THEN 1
        WHEN 5 THEN 1
        WHEN 6 THEN 0
        WHEN 7 THEN 0
    END AS 'IsWeekday', 
    DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) + 1 - DATEPART(WW, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)) + '/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate))) AS 'WeekOfMonth',
    (DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0), @CurrentDate) / 7) + 1 AS 'WeekOfQuarter',
    DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) AS 'WeekOfYear',
    DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) AS 'Month',
    DATENAME(MM, @CurrentDate) AS 'MonthName',
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (1, 4, 7, 10) THEN 1
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (2, 5, 8, 11) THEN 2
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (3, 6, 9, 12) THEN 3
    END AS 'MonthOfQuarter',
    DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate) AS 'Quarter',
    CASE DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
    END AS 'QuarterName',
    DATEPART(YEAR, @CurrentDate) AS 'Year',
    'CY ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, @CurrentDate)) AS 'YearName',
    LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @CurrentDate), 3) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)) AS 'MonthYear',
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)),2) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)) AS 'MMYYYY',
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DD, - (DATEPART(DD, @CurrentDate) - 1), @CurrentDate))) AS 'FirstDayOfMonth',
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DD, - (DATEPART(DD, (DATEADD(MM, 1, @CurrentDate)))), DATEADD(MM, 1, @CurrentDate)))) AS 'LastDayOfMonth',
    DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) AS 'FirstDayOfQuarter',
    DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, -1, @CurrentDate), -1) AS 'LastDayOfQuarter',
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate))) AS 'FirstDayOfYear',
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate))) AS 'LastDayOfYear',
    NULL AS 'HolidayName', SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @CurrentDate)END
```

From here, I'm trying to update my `Date` table with the following code `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE D
SET D.HolidayName = H.HolidayName
FROM Date AS D
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                HolidayName
            FROM GetEasterHolidays(D.Date)
            ) AS H
```

But than I get the following error message:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'.

I've tried several ways with `CAST` and such but no luck. I also tried to find out the data type and such according to these codes:

```sql
SELECT
    Table_Name,
    Column_Name,
    DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Date'
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Date'
;

SELECT
    Table_Name,
    Column_Name,
    DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'GetEasterHolidays'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Date'
```

But that doesn't give me any result either.
Can anyone help to figure this out since I'm that close to have a full date dimension table in order to work with?

PS: I'm not a real expert in coding queries but I've used a lot of the coding from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/jrgcubano/c4dbaa879a1cfc9899f961d6eafa737c).

My goal is that the Table-valued Function is updating my `Date` table so the correct records (1 day per record) will be updated in the column of `HolidayName` when it is Good Friday, Easter Sunday and Easter Monday.

I've tried already some CAST things to solve the issue, but no success so far.
I also tried to find a solution based on other posts but since I'm not that much of an expert in writing queries I couldn't figure out how their solutions would fit in to my code. My apologies upfront already in case the solution was already written elsewhere but I just didn't understand it.

Comment: You are passing a `date` to a function that expects an `int`. The error message points it out.

Comment: You need to debug your query. execute your query without  `INSERT INTO Date` and inspect the result.

Comment: @GSerg :
I tried to find out which data type is which based on the queries I gave in the last query I've written down. But in that query only gives the data type of Date (which is DATE). When CAST the D.Date to INT is gives me the error: 
"Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed."

Comment: @Squirrel :
I've done that and than I get 1 record that which shows the date of 2013-03-31. Maybe that is logical but it does not reallyhelp me to understand/find a solution direction

Comment: Why would you want to query date fields in the first place (which you are also doing wrongly because you are querying columns *named* `date` instead of *typed as* `date`, and you are only getting a meaningful result because your date-typed column happens to be *named* `Date` too)? You are literally passing a date in place of int: `GetEasterHolidays(D.Date)`, you didn't need to search for that. What do you expect to happen when you order the compiler to treat a date as an int? What value would be in that int?

Comment: @GSerg :I try to understand as good as possible, but as said in the post I'm not a full expert writing queries. To answer your question about what I'm doing wrongly: I've indeed a column being called "Date" and it is definied with a data_type of DATE.  So not sure what I'm doing wrongly in this case. Than about what you say here: "You are literally passing a date in place of int: GetEasterHolidays(D.Date)": I think that the INT is needed to let the GetEasterHolidays function work. I don't really understand this function though. I did try to change it to DATE but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It is a requirement that you understand what the function expects as its arguments before you call that function.

Comment: @GSerg : As far as I can understand the code of the function, it needs INT to calculate the days and that it has something to do with the modulo. As I've tried to understand how this function works, I did not come very far. unfortunatly. Therefore I half accepted that this code of the function should work (and it does) and I can't figure it out very much, but now running in to an error when I want to update the Date-table with it.

Comment: I've found the solution by using this code:

UPDATE Date
   SET HolidayName = H.HolidayName
   FROM Date D
   INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT 
       H.Date,
       E.HolidayName
      FROM Date H
      CROSS APPLY GetEasterHolidays(H.Year) AS E
      WHERE H.Date = E.Date
      ) H
   ON D.Date = H.Date

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Date
        SET HolidayName = H.HolidayName
        FROM Date D
        INNER JOIN
                    (
                    SELECT 
                        H.Date,
                        E.HolidayName
                    FROM Date H
                    CROSS APPLY GetEasterHolidays(H.Year) AS E
                    WHERE H.Date = E.Date
                    ) H
        ON D.Date = H.Date
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?